# Getting email messages into spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with figuring out why a script to get emails from a certain label doesn't work properly. I'm fairly new to scripting, and have searched here and elsewhere for similar posts, but couldn't find any.

Here's the script as it is now:

```
var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Test").getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var emails = messages[j].getPlainBody();

      Logger.log(messages[j].getPlainBody());
      sheet.getRange(j+1, 1).setValue(messages[j].getPlainBody());
```

I added the Logger in there to see whether it's getting the right messages, and it seems it does: it's getting 25 messages out of 40 total (in 15 threads total), and then writes: "Logging output too large. Truncating output." (the emails are long). But the order is correct, from last message through 25th (covers 9 threads out of 15).

When I then setValue() the emails into column A in the spreadsheet, it behaves very strangely. it's putting only 9 messages.. Why 9? It also seems completely arbitrary: it's getting the first thread, then it skips 2 threads and shows the second message in the 4th thread, then it goes to the next thread but skips 2 messages, then it doesn't skip anymore and adds the following 6 messages. And stops there, for no apparent reason..

The only (maybe) non-arbitrary things in this is that it starts with the 1st message in chronological order, and stops on the last message of a thread of 9 messages. But why stop there? And why skip messages and threads in between?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Just tried it with another label name, one that has only 28 messages, one thread with 27 messages and one thread with a single message. The Logger gets all of them, the setValue() skips one message arbitrarily (seems like), the one before last, which is the 1st message of the thread of 27 messages.

Comment: I finally figured it out. Phew... 
The problem was with the range to setValue() - I didn't realize the looping is done on the entire statement and not just for the extraction of the values, and as a result it was constantly going to j+1 and overwriting the previous entries. Changing the row in the range to sheet.getLastRow()+1 fixed it.